# Is there a way to set window.location so that relative paths follow this instead of what is given by default window.location

Tags: javascript, url, window.location

I have a new server and I have existing files with relative links in CSS, `img` tags, etc. How  do i set my own `window.location` to be followed by such files, I am not looking for anything hectic in particular just for within my website. e.g http://stackoverflow.com and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ I need the latter to be my `site-url`. I am thinking in the lines of `javascript` but any solution is welcome.

Comment: you are not using.... header templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you will be able to use the `<base>`-tag

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Is this cross browser compatible? let me test.

Comment: I other problem i have buddy, i see this will not work with /images/ type of path, i think i will just use jQuery to strip the first slash

Comment: Something like then `$("img").forEach(function(){ var $this = $(this), relative = $this.attr("src"); $this.attr("src", $("base").first().attr("href") + relative); });`